# What is `proof_of_work_nonce_size` used for?

Tags: protocol, nonce

I was looking at the protocol constants using:
`GET /chains/<chain_id>/blocks/<block_id>/context/constants`

and noticed these two fields:

```
  "proof_of_work_nonce_size": 8,
  "nonce_length": 32,
```

What are they used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the explanation to both these constants in the [documentation of Tezos proof of stake algorithm](https://tezos.gitlab.io/009/proof_of_stake.html).

They relate to two different nonces with different purposes.

## Proof of work anti-spam nonce

A nonce is used to prevent the chain from being spammed with blocks:

> `proof_of_work_nonce`: a nonce used to pass a low-difficulty proof-of-work for the block, as a spam prevention measure.

## Pre-commited nonces for increasing entropy

In the section on [Random seeds](https://tezos.gitlab.io/009/proof_of_stake.html#random-seed), you can read about nonces (whose length is `nonce_length`) using the on-chain random number generation used to select baking slots. In sum, in each cycle the algorithm assigns baking slots randomly using a based on random seed calculated a set of pre-commited "nonces" from bakers from previous cycles:

> The random seed for cycle n is a 256-bit number generated at the very
> end of cycle n-1 from nonces to which delegates commit during cycle
> n-2. One out of every BLOCKS_PER_COMMITMENT = 32 blocks can contain a
> commitment. There are therefore at most BLOCKS_PER_CYCLE /
> BLOCKS_PER_COMMITMENT = 128 commitments. A commitment is the hash of a
> nonce. The commitment is generated by the baker who produces the block
> and is included in the block header.